# React Router and BrowserSync

Tags: react-router, browser-sync

I'm learning how to use react-router and my usual starter for projects use Gulp and BrowserSync. The problem is, when I start to nest my routes, my bundle.js is not getting served and getting 404.

Below is my code:

```
gulp.task('build-js', function() {
    return browserify({
      entries: ['./app/src/index.js'],
      transform: babelify
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

gulp.task('init', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
          baseDir: './',
          middleware: [historyApiFallback()],
          index: 'index.html'
        }
    });
});
```

React Routes:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
       <Route path="about/page" component={About} />
       <Route path="posts" component={PostsNew} />
</Route>
```

IndexRoute and posts work fine, but when I go to localhost:3000/about/page, I get 404 saying bundle.js is not found. Console is showing localhost:3000/about/bundle.js for some reason but in fact, my bundle.js is suppose to be served on the root folder.

Can someone tell me what's going on?

Comment: Also, please note that ./app is not my root folder. If that helps.